# Unknown method error in Visualforce

Tags: visualforce

Why am I getting this error - Unknown method redirectToPage?

```
<apex:commandButton id="btn_questionnaire" value="Learn More" action="{!RedirectToPage}" reRender="true">
            <apex:param name="JobName" value="{!jl.Name}" assignTo="{!JobName}"/>
```

```
    public with sharing class Volunteer_JobController 
{

 public PageReference RedirecttoPage(String jName)
    {

        PageReference redirectPage = Page.JobQuestions;
        redirectPage.setRedirect(true);
        return redirectPage;
    }   

public String JobName{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Change to: public PageReference RedirecttoPage() and are you sure that you have to controller in the controller="Volunteer_JobController" or extensions="Volunteer_JobController" on the page?

Comment: I need the parameter in the method later, hence I'm not removing it.  I have this in my VF page

<apex:page standardController="GW_Volunteers__Volunteer_Job__c" extensions="Volunteer_JobController" showHeader="false" >

and I have the same extension class for the standard controller. The VF page just works fine without this command button

Comment: I've posted an answer as well, but rereading your question, I kind of wonder what exactly you're trying to achieve? Why are you passing a parameter at all? It seems that your apex function doesn't have any logic involving the value of jobName.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `<apex:param>` in combination with the apex function like this. The function you specify in the action attribute of the commandButton should always be defined without parameters in the controller. In your case: `public PageReference redirectToPage()`. When the button is clicked, first the parameters that are specified in the button are assigned to the respective `assignTo` attributes. After that, the action function of the button is called.